# Signification de « assez... pour que »

Tags: grammaire, sens, subjonctif

Pourriez-vous m'aider à comprendre cette phrase :

> Cet avocat de renom est assez persuasif pour que les jurés soient vite
>   convaincus de l'innocence de son client.

Est-ce que cela implique que les jurés vont être convaincus ou non ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cet avocat de renom**

- Il est avocat, et il est connu et estimé

**est assez persuasif pour...**

- Il possède suffisamment de capacité de convaincre les gens pour...

**que les jurés soient vite convaicus**

- Les jurés ***seront rapidement convaincus,*** grâce aux grandes capacités de l’avocat

**de l’innocence de son client**

- Que le client de l’avocat (l’accusé) est innocent

Comme les événements sont dans le futur, tout est hypothétique. On infère à partir des aptitudes connues de l’avocat, et **possiblement** aussi de la naïveté des jurés.

---

On pourrait reformuler sans le ***que*** (et en simplifiant un peu) :

> Cet avocat est **assez persuasif pour convaincre les jurés** de l’innocence de son client.

Answer (score 1):

> Cet avocat de renom est **assez** persuasif **pour que** les jurés soient vite convaincus de l'innocence de son client.

Cela signifie que le talent de l'avocat est suffisant pour convaincre les jurés  rapidement.

*Autre formulation (pas tellement plus facile en raison de la tendance à confondre avec le but.*)

- Cet avocat de renom a un pouvoir de persuasion suffisant pour convaincre rapidement les jurés de l'innocence de son client.

On ne peut pas dire cependant « les jurés seront convaincus »; la réalisation de l'action reste dans le domaine des possibilités, ce qui explique le subjonctif dans la formulation originale et l'infinitif dans la reformulation.

L'usage de « pour » avec « que » présente cependant une difficulté; cette locution est surchargée de sens et trois sens principaux au moins sont en concurrence ; les définitions et exemples ci-dessous sont tirés du TLFi (fond jaune); les caractères en gras ont été ajoutés ; le sens concerné est le premier ; la combinaison de mots « pour que » est à comprendre ici comme étant une locution conjonctive exprimant la conséquence ; avec cette locution le subjonctif est toujours nécessaire ([ref](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238)).

*CONSÉQUENCE*

> [En corrél. avec une idée d'intensité] Trop, assez, pas assez, suffisamment pour...
>
> - Il y a **assez** de désert **pour que**, du centre, on ne voie point d'autre horizon.
> - Il pleut cependant **trop fort pour que** je puisse me promener dans les bois.

Pour référence sont donnés ci-dessous d'autres constructions importantes qu'il ne faut pas confondre (lecture non nécessaire à la compréhension de ce qui précède).

*CAUSALITÉ FINALE, BUT*

> pour que Synon. de **afin que** (ce dernier appartenant à la lang. écrite)
>   a) [En réponse à la question pourquoi?]
>
> - Coupez-le bien proprement, pour que ça ne se voie pas.
> - Tu veux vraiment aller là-bas? Bien sûr. Et pour quoi faire? C'est pour que le petit ait un père.
> - ... elle a prononcé vivement une parole que je ne peux analyser sans me faire du mal : « Je vous dis cela pour que vous ne soyez pas étonné quand vous apprendrez que je suis allée à Toulouse... »
> - [Dans le champ de la nég.] À quoi employez-vous donc vos journées?... je ne vous paie pas pour que vous flâniez du matin au soir
>
> [Dans une phrase exclam.] P. iron
>
> - ... Duplat tué, Blackman tué, les gardes anglaises mutilées, vingt bataillons français, sur les quarante du corps de Reille, décimés, trois mille hommes, dans cette seule masure de Hougomont, sabrés, écharpés, égorgés, fusillés, brûlés; et tout cela pour qu'aujourd'hui un paysan dise à un voyageur : Monsieur, donnez-moi trois francs; si vous aimez, je vous expliquerai la chose de Waterloo!
>
> b) [Le compl. final appartient au thème]
>
> - Mais, pour que la densité de la voie lactée devînt homogène, il faudrait répartir la masse du soleil.
> - Je peux bien te l'avouer : pour que notre bonheur ait été possible, il a fallu que ce mariage manqué leur ait porté à la tête.
>     Rem. Dans cet empl., le verbe de la princ. est souvent devoir ou falloir. La princ. exprime alors la condition nécessaire à la réalisation de ce qui est dit dans la sub.
>
> [Dans une question]
>
> - Qu'est-ce que les Grandet font donc à leur grande Nanon pour qu'elle leur soit si attachée? Elle passerait dans le feu pour eux!
>     Rem. Pop. pour ne pas que (p. anal. avec pour ne pas + inf.) : pour ne pas qu'il vienne? « pour qu'il ne vienne pas ».

*CAUSE*

> [Dans des phrases nég., interr., hyp.]
>
> - « Qui est cette personne? Elle est bien belle », demanda-t-il en voyant la Viennoise. « Mais qu'a-t-elle donc pour que lui aussi la trouve belle? ».